# How to create screen indicator in OS X application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface

Launchpad in OS X has a screen indicator at the bottom of the screen that looks like this:

[image]

How can I create the same in my application for switching between different views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inspired by an iOS class called `UIPageControl`. There's no OS X equivalent of this, but you can create a custom view for it. Someone's already done it in GitHub called [BFPageControl](https://github.com/bfolder/BFPageControl) if you want to try using it.

Comment: There is `NSPageController` already which is useful to animate the switching but it just missing the page indicators..
[Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/samplecode/PictureSwiper/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011096)

Comment: @corro Ah yes, I didn't know that. But that GitHub library does give you the page indicators. But IMO the reason why it's not standard in OS X is because all scroll views usually just use scroll bars.

Answer (score 1):

You can use buttons configured to behave as radio buttons. For example, button cells with style Inline, type On Off, embedded in a matrix with mode Radio will work. Set the cell size to be a square. (`NSMatrix` and `NSCell` are deprecated. In theory, you can get buttons to behave as radio buttons without them, but making them styled as inline buttons rather than ordinary radio buttons is a nuisance. You could also manage the "radio" behavior, where only one is one at a time, manually. It's not hard.)

With no title or image, the inline button cell will fill a circle with either gray or white, depending on its `backgroundStyle`. Or, you could provide two images for the on and off states.